# Most power efficient way of implementing an Android notification app

Tags: android, notifications, wifi, push, mqtt

I'm developing an Android notification app which gets XML data in an MQTT message to build the notification but also contains data to perform an Intent when the Notification is clicked on.
I implemented Push messaging over using Polling/Pull messaging as I assumed it would be much more efficient to wait for a message to arrive and do something with it over polling a web server for an update and parsing results which may not have any new data.

However, Android's default power saving scheme turns off wi-fi when the screen is off to save power, which means my connection to the MQTT server drops. When I turn back on the screen, my server connection is re-established and the last message on the MQTT server is delivered.

So now I'm faced with a choice. Implement a wi-fi lock in my service code, or use Alarm manager to have my service periodically wake,check for an MQTT publsh and then exit.

This [wifi wakelock vs. alarm manager](http://goltermann.cc/2011/11/android-accessing-wifi-even-in-standby-using-wakelock-wifilock-alarmmanager-and-services/) suggests that wifilocks are very power inefficient and I should use alarm manager.
If that's the case, I loose the "instant deliver" advantage of push notification and I'm effictively polling for data.
How do apps like Google's cloud messaging/WhatsApp/Viber do instant messaging while allowing the device to sleep and not draining the battery by keeping wi-fi active?

Answer (score 2):

Since MQTT is suitable to use of mobile networks unless your on a device that is wifi only, you only need to take a WakeLock to stop the CPU from sleeping so you can communicate with the MQTT server. You can write your service to attempt reconnect if the connection to the server is lost.

However, on wifi only devices you will need to take the WifiLock for you to continue to be connected to the MQTT server. With regards to battery life you will need to do some testing to see the implications on battery life for the wifi only devices.